# Swift - Bad Quality image when loaded in PDF - using TPPDF

Tags: ios, swift, pdf

While using `TPPDF library`, when a high-quality image is loaded inside a pdf, the image turns blurry.

I tried all the possible methods.

**Here is my Code:**

```
let coverImage = PDFImage(image: UIImage(named: "Banner")!, quality: 1, options: [.resize])

    //To find proportional width and height
    let imageWidth: CGFloat = coverImage.image.size.width
    let imageHeight: CGFloat = coverImage.image.size.height

    let targetHeight: CGFloat = imageHeight/imageWidth

    print("PdfWidth", pdf.layout.width)
    print("PdfHeight", pdf.layout.height)
    print("TargetHeight", pdf.layout.width*targetHeight)

    print("ImageWidth", coverImage.image.size.width)
    print("ImageHeight", coverImage.image.size.height)

    coverImage.size = CGSize(width: pdf.layout.width, height: pdf.layout.width*targetHeight)
    print("size", coverImage.size)
    pdf.addImage(.contentCenter, image: coverImage)
```

**log, I get is:**

```
PdfWidth 595.0
PdfHeight 842.0
TargetHeight 44.5
ImageWidth 595.0
ImageHeight 44.5
size (595.0, 44.5)
```

I also tried to add a high-resolution image of 8000x600, but still, the image is blurry.

Comment: `To optimize file size, images are resized and compressed using JPEG compression. By default both is enabled, but can change them by setting options on the image instance.

If resizing is enabled, the image will be resized to its frame size in the document. If compression is enabled, the image will be compressed using the value set in the property quality. This value ranges from between 0.0 for bad quality and 1.0 for best quality - default is set to 0.85, which resolves in a good balance between compression and quality.`

Comment: Since you are using 1 for image quality it is unlikely to be a jpeg compression problem. Have you tried any of the other resizing options? Also the author of that library is quite responsive so feel free to contact him directly.

Comment: @Magnas Can you please elaborate on "Other resizing options"  if you are implying this --> options: [.resize] then we have other options as "compress". 
Also I am new to coding environment, can you please let me know how to contact the author of that library?

Comment: I just downloaded and viewed the source code for the library. It looks like `.resize` and `.compress` are the only two options so they're probably not the answer to your problem. Can you confirm that you experience the same problem when your image quality value is the default 0.85? I'd rather not link the author's email here but if you click on `techprimate` at the top of the TPPDF GitHub page you'll see his address at the top of the next page.

Comment: @Magnas thank you for your quick response, i have mailed techprimate, will be updating you when i get a response. Again thank you

Comment: Hi I'm Phil from techprimate, looks like your image gets downscaled to fit the page. Have you tried to remove the .resize option? Also this might be related to issue #109 on Github https://github.com/techprimate/TPPDF/issues/109, if neither one works for your, please feel free to open a new git issue, but please provide an example image which does reproduce the issue

Comment: Please refer https://github.com/techprimate/TPPDF/issues/121, for this issue